# JavaScript: Handling function argument with default value of true

Tags: javascript

Is there any way to make a shorthand for `var x = false || true;`? Because the provided example always evaluates to true. For example, in this function:

```
function load(bool) {
    loading = bool || true;
}
```

`loading` is always evaluated as true.

With the help of lodash, I tried `loading = ( !_.isUndefined(bool) ) ? bool : true;`. Otherwise, It could have been written as `loading = ( typeof bool !== undefined ) ? bool : true;`. But I found this to be verbose and long.

**EDIT**: for clarification purposes, I'd like a better workaround (compared to my attempt) for `x = false || false`, where in bool could either be `true` or `false` (and `false` does not work for this situation because it will evaluate only to true).

Comment: `whatever || true` is always `true` unless the first is not a boolean expression (and not evaluated to undefined, null, "", 0)

Comment: It seems you want `typeof bool == 'undefined'? true : bool`, but I can't imagine why you want that.

Comment: What logic exactly do you want to apply? If it's `undefined`, it should be `true`, otherwise it should be `!!bool`?

Comment: @deceze—I suppose bool can be true, false or undefined. The OP wants undefined converted to true and the others left alone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about

```
(bool == null) ? true : bool;
```

As mentioned by @RobG, we can even make it more concise by this:

```
(bool == null) || bool;
```

Comment: If the OP wants concise, then `bool==null?true:bool` might suit. Not my cup of tea though. Nor is `null==x||x` but it's less still.

Comment: Ah! yes, that's another level of reducing the size of the statement. I will update my answer with your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be explicit about the fact that you are giving this parameter a default value of true, then you could consult `arguments.length`:

```
bool = arguments.length ? bool : true;
```

or

```
bool = bool || !arguments.length;
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea regarding ```arguments```. I accepted Lokesh's answer since it sounds more explicit (not referring to the post content).